# Undertsanding docker build

Tags: docker

When I run a docker build command i see the following

```
[root@hadoop01 myjavadir]# docker build -t runhelloworld .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.096 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM java
 ---> 3323938eb5a2
Step 1 : MAINTAINER priyanka priyanka.patil@subex.com
 ---> Running in 89fa73dbc2b8
 ---> 827afdfa3d71
Removing intermediate container 89fa73dbc2b8
Step 2 : COPY ./HelloWorld.java .
 ---> 9e547d78d08c
Removing intermediate container ff5b7c7a8122
Step 3 : RUN javac HelloWorld.java
 ---> Running in d52f3093d6a3
 ---> 86121aadfc67
Removing intermediate container d52f3093d6a3
Step 4 : CMD java HelloWorld
 ---> Running in 7b4fa1b8ed37
 ---> 6eadaac27986
Removing intermediate container 7b4fa1b8ed37
Successfully built 6eadaac27986
```

Want to understand the meaning of these container ids like 7b4fa1b8ed37.
What does it mean when the daemon says "Removing intermediate container d52f3093d6a3"?

Answer (score 2):

The `docker build` process automates what is happening in the [Creating your own images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/) section of the docker docs.

In your case above:

- The image ID we're going to start with is `3323938eb5a2` (the ID of the `java` image)
- from that image we run a container (after it's created it has a container ID of `89fa73dbc2b8`) to set the `MAINTAINER` meta data, docker commits the changes and the resulting layer ID is `827afdfa3d71`
- because we're finished with the container `89fa73dbc2b8`, we can remove it
- from the layer we created from the `MAINTAINER` line, we create a new container to run the command `COPY ./HelloWorld.java .` which gets a container ID of `ff5b7c7a8122`, docker commits the changes and the resulting layer ID is `9e547d78d08c`
- because we're finished with the container `ff5b7c7a8122`, we can remove it

Repeat for steps 3 and 4.

Comment: But want to understand from the docker daemon perspective. Is a separate image created for every line of instruction?. What does it mean my docker commit?. Who assigns the image ids?

Comment: A separate layer is created for every line in your `Dockerfile`. Commit in this context means a layer is created from the current state of a container. The layer IDs are assigned by the docker daemon.